# Can you install exported site config as part of a kernel test?

Tags: configuration, 9, testing

I am using the Configuration Sync module to export config specific to my site out into a config directory that lives outside my main Drupal directory.

When writing kernel tests I know that you can use `$this->installConfig()` and specify a module(s) to install default config from, but how can I specify certain (or all) config files from that directory to be installed inside of a kernel test?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to install some separately, determine which you would like to install together and place them in a new module together. Then you can install different combinations by specifying which modules to install.

Comment: I agree that is definitely a way, but that seems contrary to how the config export works. It already gives me a directory full of config files. I feel I should be able to use something `$this->installConfig('config_sync') to install them during a test.

Comment: That’s like saying that you should be able to install a module, but specify which entities are installed, or which blocks. A module is a self contained collection of code that implements a feature. If you need only one part of that, then it is a dependency and should get split off into a separate module.